# how to stop the looping if the condition satisfies in the first level

Tags: python

if the difference of the any two elements in my list is equal to n,
then I have show the out as True else False

I have updated the code details i the "SHOW SOME CODE" area.please refer it

```
my_list = [1,3,4,9]
n = len(my_list) 
z = 3
def checking(my_list,z): 
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, n):           
        for j in range(i+1, n):         
            if my_list[i] - my_list[j] == z or my_list[j] - my_list[i] == z: 
                print('yes')
            else:
                print('No')
print(checking(my_list,z))
```

Expecting : if my list is-[1,3,4,9] and Z=3
then I am expecting just true as my output (becauase 4-1=3)
I used 2 loops .can I solve this with only one loop

Actual:in the same example above I am getting the below output
No
yes
No
No
No
No
None

Answer (score 2):

You can use `combinations` from `itertools` module to generate pairs of your list and return True if the condition is satisfied otherwise return false. I have added a print line just so you can see which combinations it processes. I have also used `True` or `False` as thats what you say in you

```
from itertools import combinations


def checking(my_list, z):
    for i, j in combinations(my_list, 2):
        print("Checking pair: i=",  i,  ", j=", j)
        if i - j == z or j - i == z:
            return True
    print("no matches found")
    return False


my_list = [1, 3, 4, 9]
my_list2 = [1, 3, 5, 9]
z = 3
print(checking(my_list, z))
print(checking(my_list2, z))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Checking pair: i= 1 , j= 3
Checking pair: i= 1 , j= 4
True
Checking pair: i= 1 , j= 3
Checking pair: i= 1 , j= 5
Checking pair: i= 1 , j= 9
Checking pair: i= 3 , j= 5
Checking pair: i= 3 , j= 9
Checking pair: i= 5 , j= 9
no matches found
False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

def checking(my_list,z): 
    for i in range(0, n):           
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if abs(my_list[i] - my_list[j]) == z : 
                return 'yes' # return ends the loop, by ending the entire function call
            # else: # comment out if you don't want the "no"s printed
            #     print('No. (Iteration i={}, j={})'.format(i,j)) # comment out if you don't want the "no"s printed
    # if it reaches here, then the both the loops finished 
    # without finding a True condition. 
    # So simply return the No (no reason for an else.)
    return ("No") 

my_list = [1,3,4,9]
n = len(my_list) 
z = 3
print("First run with [{}]".format(my_list))
print(checking(my_list,z))

my_list = [1,1,1,1]
n = len(my_list) 
z = 3
print("First run with [{}]".format(my_list))
print(checking(my_list,z))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
First run with [[1, 3, 4, 9]]
yes
First run with [[1, 1, 1, 1]]
No
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply.unfortunately I got output as No and Yes(both)..                       I am expecting only 'Yes' in this case as one my condition satifies(4-1=3)                                 I want No if the condition is not satified. Also can this be possible with using for loop only for one time.

Comment: yes. Note the comments in the code. If you leave in the `print("no")` you will get a no on every iteration that is not yes. Let me edit the code to make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a break statement after the print statement in the conditional. This is used to step out of whatever conditional or loop you are in. This is assuming you are not doing this in a method, which in that case I'd suggest returning 'yes' which automatically exits the function. Either or should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use one flag. when the condition is true just set the flag to 1 and break the loop. if flag is not set to 1 continue to check.

```
my_list = [1,3,4,9]
n = len(my_list) 
z = 3
flag = 0
def checking(my_list,z): 
    for i in range(0, n) and flag is 0:           
        for j in range(i+1, n) and flag is 0:         
            if my_list[i] - my_list[j] == z or my_list[j] - my_list[i] == z: 
                flag = 1
if flag is 1:
  print("True")
else:
  print("False")
```

Answer (score 0):

For : "Expecting : if my list is-[1,3,4,9] and Z=3 then I am expecting just true as my output (becauase 4-1=3) I used 2 loops .**can I solve this with only one loop**"

Here is the solution using binary search [IMP: to perform binary search your list should be sorted]:

```
def checking(my_list, z):
    low = 0
    high = len(my_list)-1
    while low < high:
        find = my_list[high] - my_list[low]
        if find == z:
            return True
        else:
            if find > z:
                high -=1
            else:
                low +=1
    return False

print(checking([1,3,4,9],3))
print(checking([1,2,2,3],9))
```

Visit this link  great resource on Data Structure using Python:
https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/SortSearch/TheBinarySearch.html

There is another approach to make this more efficient i.e. Hashing. Will leave that for you to research for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to achieve your goal by using a `list comprehensions`.

> Here, I use the **absolute difference** `abs()`. The real difference version is below (in the update part).

```
my_list = [1,3,4,9]
z = 3

def checking(my_list,z):
    outputs = [abs(i-j) for i in my_list for j in my_list if i != j and abs(i-j) == z]

    if len(outputs):
        print("Yes") # you can delete this line
        return True
    else:
        print("No") # you can delete this
        return False

# testing
print(checking(my_list, z))
```

> **Output:**

```
Yes
True
```

> **UPDATE:** The version below use the real difference and not the absolute difference.

```
my_list = [1,3,4,9]
z = 3

def checking(my_list,z):
    outputs = [(i-j) for i in my_list for j in my_list if i != j and (i-j) == z]

    if len(outputs):
        print("Yes") # you can delete this line
        return True
    else:
        print("No") # you can delete this
        return False

# testing
print(checking(my_list, z))
```

> **Output:**

```
Yes
True
```

With this version, if `z = -3`, the result will be:

```
Yes
True
```

Comment: Have you tried for `z=-3` cause there is a valid combination where `1 - 4 = -3`

Comment: See my code, you will see `abs(i-j) == z`. I will ask @nishank if he wants `i-j == z` or `abs(i-j) == z` ..

Comment: I updated the code, so the two differences (**real** and **absolute**) are there.